# Вывод данных из mysql с помощью php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть база данных db_cars
Запрос к базе данных должен выводить марку и модель автомобиля, свойства которого укажет пользователь.
Если запрос забить в SQLyog с определёнными данными то всё работает, через php ничего не получается ни определённые данные, не данные которые вводит пользователь.

Облазил уже всё, пересмотрел код огромное кол-во раз.

Структура БД:
cars: brand model fuel_consumprion engine_code body_code
car_engine: engine_code fuel_type engine_capacity
body_car: body_code doors_number

```html
<html>

<body>
  <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $search_car = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'search_car');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Russian_Russia.65001'); 
    if ($search_car) {
      $engine_capacity = $_POST['engine_capacity'];
      $doorts_number = $_POST['doorts_number'];
      $fuel_type = $_POST['fuel_type'];
      $fuel_consumption = $_POST['fuel_consumption'];
      mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

      $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "sa", "db_cars");
      if(mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
       die("Помилка з'єднання: ".mysqli_connect_error());} 
      
      else { 
 mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8');
 $engine_capacity = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $engine_capacity);
 $doorts_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $doorts_number);
 $fuel_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $fuel_type);
 $fuel_consumption = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $fuel_consumption);
 $sql_cons = "SELECT `brand`,`model` FROM `cars` INNER JOIN `car_engine` ON `cars`.`engine_code` = `car_engine`.`engine_code` INNER JOIN `body_car` ON `cars`.`body_code` = `body_car`.`body_code`
  WHERE `engine_capacity` = '$engine_capacity' AND `doorts_number` = '$doorts_number' AND `fuel_type` = '$fuel_type' AND `fuel_consumption` = '$fuel_consumption';";
  printf("Виконується запит.\n",$sql_cons, $sql_2);
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_cons, $sql_2);
 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
 echo "<table border=1>\n";
          echo "<tr><td>Бренд</td>
            <td>Модель</td></tr>\n";
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
          printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n",$row["brand"],$row["model"]); 
   };
          echo "</table>\n";
 mysqli_free_result($result);
 } 
}
} else { // відобразити форму
?>
    <P>
      <H3 ALIGN=CENTER> Пошук автомобілей </H3>
      <P> Вкажіть дані автомобіля, які вас цікавлять:
        <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
          <p>Потужність двигуна <input name="engine_capacity" size="10"></p>
          <P> Кількість дверей:
            <INPUT NAME="doorts_number" SIZE="2">
            <p> Тип палива
              <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="fuel_type" value="petrol" checked="checked">Бензин
              <input type="radio" name="fuel_type" value="gas"> Газ
              <input type="radio" name="fuel_type" value="diesel"> Дизель
              <input type="radio" name="fuel_type" value="electro">Електрика</p>
            <p>Витрата пального <input name="fuel_consumption" size="5"></p>
            <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT name="search_car" value="Шукати">
            <INPUT TYPE=RESET>
        </FORM>
        <?php
    }    // end if    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Во первых использовать простой mysqli и экранизировать запросы это такое себе, прочтите про PDO. Во вторых есть не сложная технология ajax которая без обновления страницы выполнит нужные вам изменения.
Ещё строка которая выводит то что нужно

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n",$row["brand"],$row["model"]); 
};
```

попробуй заменить на

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n",$row["brand"],$row["model"]); 
};
```

Comment: Изменил, всё равно ничего не выводит(